# Why when i select count with php i get just 1 instead of .. 55 for example || PHP Count, From last 100

Tags: php, mysql, select, count

```
    $nr333 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM (
    SELECT * FROM games 
    WHERE human = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[human])."'
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100
) tmp WHERE changed = 'y'", $link) or die(mysql_error());
$frecventa333 = mysql_num_rows($nr333);
```

so bassicaly i  dont get any error but .. instead of getting the real number i get just 1:|
http://s017.radikal.ru/i414/1310/a2/37958f7cdb48.png

Comment: Clothilda? Seriously? http://stackoverflow.com/q/19350509/251311

Comment: $nr333 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM ( SELECT * FROM games WHERE human = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[human])."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100 ) AS total WHERE changed = 'y'", $link) or die(mysql_error()); $frecventa333 = mysql_num_rows($nr333); $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($nr333); echo $data['total'];

Comment: Stop posting code in comments.

Comment: Stop creating multiple accounts and asking the same questions

Answer (score 2):

That's because `COUNT` returns only one row, always. But in that row you'll find field with all rows counted, in one integer.

Try to fetch that row.

And next thing you should do is checking `PDO` extension. It's better than deprecated `mysql_*` functions and isn't so hard to learn.

Comment: ok i updated data `$nr333 = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM (
    SELECT * FROM games 
    WHERE human = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET[human])."'
    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 100
) AS total WHERE changed = 'y'", $link) or die(mysql_error());
$frecventa333 = mysql_num_rows($nr333); 
$data=mysql_fetch_assoc($nr333);
echo $data['total'];` but stll not getting anything

Comment: @ClotildaHuston You set `AS cnt` co why are you trying to get if from `$data['total']`?